# changing the max-width of the embedded tweet

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, twitter

I am trying to embed the twitter feed into my angular 2 application but  there are max-width restrictions on the tweets set between 250 to 550 pixels (https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-tweets/parameters). Is there a way to change the max-width to 100% without using j-query. It should basically cover the entire grey background. Thank you in advance.

```js
!function (d, s, id) {
      var js,
        fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        p = 'https';
      if (!d.getElementById(id)) {

        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }
    }

    (document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
```

```css
.SandboxRoot {
  width: 100% !important;
}
div {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100% !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  min-width: 100% !important;
}
.EmbeddedTweet{
  width: 100% !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  min-width: 100% !important;
}
div twitterwidget {
  width: 100% !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  min-width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en">
       <a href="https://twitter.com/Interior/status/463440424141459456?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw"></a>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
</div>

<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

Target using `twitterwidget::shadow` selector

```js
! function(d, s, id) {
  var js,
    fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    p = 'https';
  if (!d.getElementById(id)) {

    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }
}

(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
```

```css
.SandboxRoot {
  width: 100% !important;
}

div {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100% !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  min-width: 100% !important;
}

twitterwidget::shadow .EmbeddedTweet {
  width: 100% !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  min-width: 100% !important;
}

div twitterwidget {
  width: 100% !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  min-width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en">
      <a href="https://twitter.com/Interior/status/463440424141459456?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw"></a>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
</div>

<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```